# React - console log gives blank object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to react and im trying to import a list of objects from a js file and set them as the inital state of my app like so:

```
import allSamples from './reducers/reducerSamples';

var App = React.createClass({
        getInitialState () {
        return {
            samples:{allSamples},
        }   
    },
    render () {
        ...
```

Here is my js file with object:

```
var allSamples = [
            {
            id:"1",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_909dwsd.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        },
            {
            id:"2",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_chicago.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        },
            {
            id:"3",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_dandans.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        },
            {
            id:"4",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_deephouser.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        },
            {
            id:"5",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_diesel.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        },
            {
            id:"6",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_dropped.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        }
 ]
```

The state in React dev tools says "empty object", am I not importing the file properly? Can't find anyone else with similar issues SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things that can be going on here:

- try `console.log(allSamples);` above `var App ..` to make sure you're pulling it in correctly.
- make sure the `{ samples: {allSamples} }` syntax is supported by your transpiler. Or just say `{ samples: allSamples }` to see if that works.

Comment: thanks Peter. The console log brings up and empty object and I tried doing just samples: allSamples  but again, blank state

Comment: Oh, you need to export `allSamples` in the other file. Just say `export default [` instead of `var allSamples = [`. You can just export it in this case, no need to name the array.

Comment: That was it! didn't realise you had to export objects aswell, thought it was only react components!

Comment: You can only import things you've exported in other files, everything else will be private to its host file. React components are basically functions, and they obey the same rules. Glad it worked :).